# Knoockout computed observable write doesnt update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

The following is a computed observable, and i an calling its write function, but the write doesnt update the value for the computed.

```
self.pagesToBeDisplayed = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
       return self.pages();
    }, write: function (totalCount) {
        self.pages(totalCount) 
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
});
```

I am calling the above observable as 
`self.pagesToBeDisplayed(5)`. However, only the value for `self.pages` is updated and 
 `self.pagesToBeDisplayed` is still the older value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working as expected:

```js
var viewmodel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.pages = ko.observable(2);
  self.pagesToBeDisplayed = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
       return self.pages();
    }, write: function (totalCount) {
        self.pages(totalCount) 
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
  });
  
  self.update = function(){
    self.pagesToBeDisplayed(5);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

Update via input:
<input type="number" data-bind="value: pagesToBeDisplayed">
<br>

Update via JS:
<button data-bind="click: update">Update</button>

<br><br>
Latest values:
<br>
self.pages:<span data-bind="text: pages"></span>
<br>
self.pagesToBeDisplayed:<span data-bind="text: pagesToBeDisplayed"></span>
```

It's probably some other part of your code that is causing the problem.